# How to get multiple celery task results at same time?

Tags: python, celery

So we can use `sometask.appy_async()` to start a celery task, and `sometask.AsyncResult(task_id)` to query the result.

The situation now is I started some tasks, and I want to query their results at same time. The pseudocode would be: `sometask.AsyncResult(task_1, task_2, task_3)`

I use Redis to store the result, and I know in Redis you can use `MGET KEY1 KEY2 .. KEYN` to retrieve multiple key-values in one command. So how can I do it in celery?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to accomplish that is to use Celery workflows. More precisely - the [Group](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#groups) primitive. What is important about Group is that it returns [GroupResult](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#group-results) (think of it as collection of AsyncResults).